# Audio sample rate timing

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am using NAudio to generate some tones for a motion control application.  The audio format is 16kHz mono.  Correct me if I wrong here: A hertz is one second so that means we have 16,000 samples per second or 16 samples per millisecond.  The samples in NAudio are provided as an array of 1600 float values.

Does this mean that I can output 16 discrete values per millisecond over the headphone jack?

Comment: I dont get this part "The samples in NAudio are provided as an array of 1600 float values.". You mean 16000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are partly right, depending on what exactly is meant by 16 kHz mono. If it is expressed such that you configured NAudio to output audio at 16000 samples per second, then 16 samples per millisecond is what you need.

On the other hand if you need to output audio at frequencies on up to 16 kHz mono, then you will need to configure NAudio to output at 32K samples per second, because of [Shannon's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).